# Get len(dataset) = 0 in object detection problem

Tags: python, neural-network, albumentations

I'm solving the problem of object detection on a fruit dataset: https://yadi.sk/d/UPwQB7OZrB48qQ.
I was given the code for my dataset class:

```
class2tag = {"apple": 1, "orange": 2, "banana": 3}


class FruitDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_dir, transform=None):
        self.images = []
        self.annotations = []
        self.transform = transform
        for annotation in glob.glob(data_dir + "/*xml"):
            image_fname = os.path.splitext(annotation)[0] + ".jpg"
            self.images.append(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image_fname), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            with open(annotation) as f:
                annotation_dict = xmltodict.parse(f.read())
            bboxes = []
            labels = []
            objects = annotation_dict["annotation"]["object"]
            if not isinstance(objects, list):
                objects = [objects]
            for obj in objects:
                bndbox = obj["bndbox"]
                bbox = [bndbox["xmin"], bndbox["ymin"], bndbox["xmax"], bndbox["ymax"]]
                bbox = list(map(int, bbox))
                bboxes.append(torch.tensor(bbox))
                labels.append(class2tag[obj["name"]])
            self.annotations.append(
                {"boxes": torch.stack(bboxes).float(), "labels": torch.tensor(labels)}
            )

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if self.transform:
            # the following code is correct if you use albumentations
            # if you use torchvision transforms you have to modify it =)
            res = self.transform(
                image=self.images[i],
                bboxes=self.annotations[i]["boxes"],
                labels=self.annotations[i]["labels"],
            )
            return res["image"], {
                "boxes": torch.tensor(res["bboxes"]),
                "labels": torch.tensor(res["labels"]),
            }
        else:
            return self.images[i], self.annotations[i]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)
```

I'm doing my project in Google Colab, so I've mounted Google Drive and unzipped archive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then I did some augmentations using albumentations:

```
train_transform = A.Compose([
                             A.Flip(p=0.25),
                             A.RGBShift(p=0.2),
                             ], bbox_params=A.BboxParams(format='coco'))
val_transform = A.Compose([], bbox_params=A.BboxParams(format='coco'))

train_dataset = FruitDataset("./train_zip/train", transform=train_transform)
val_dataset = FruitDataset("./test_zip/test", transform=val_transform)
```

However, when I run `len(train_dataset)`, I get the value of 0. So, I cannot get why my dataset size is 0. Neither can I understand where the problem is.
Would be very grateful for any possible advice.

Comment: Did you check that `train_zip/train` contains `xml` files? What do you get with, e.g., `os.listdir("train_zip/train")`?

Comment: @Holt, everything is fine with the path, there are jpg and xml. For the second code I get a list of names of all my files.

Comment: Well, it's working after I run: 
`import os;
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive");
!ls;
os.listdir("./train_zip/train")`

But I don't understand why.